# Why did the bottom water heater element fail before the top when run empty?

Tags: electrical, water-heater

I rather stupidly drained my electric water heater without shutting the power off.

When I refilled it, it did not heat, which is expected. I assumed I blew the top heating element as it drained, which would have then shut off the bottom heating element or perhaps both would blow.

However, when I took out a multimeter to test, the top heating element seems OK (set to 2kΩ registers .01), whereas the bottom seems shot (registered 1.5).

I am worried I am misunderstanding something though, as I don't see how draining a water tank can cause the bottom heating element to fail, while leaving the top one intact. It seems like either both need to blow, or just the top.

Do I have my interpretation of the multimeter reading backward? Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: My understanding is that a good element reads 15-60 ohms. Neither 0.01 ohms nor 1.5 ohms seem like good readings.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess what then confuses me is that I got a completely new 4500w element, and it read 0.01 when I took it out of the box?

Comment: Are you reading your meter correctly? I'm still confused by ranged meters sometimes.

Comment: Given that it is set to 2kΩ, I guess I multiply by 100x to get the # of ohms?

If so, I guess my reading of 1.5 would mean 150 ohms for the bottom, whereas my .01 would be ~10 ohms for the bottom (although could easily be 16, as it is really imprecise at that point with no units between .01 and .02.

Comment: @evt  On kohms, you'd multiply by 1000.  So 1.5 would be 1500 and .01 would be 10.  depending on what the instructions say for your meter.

Comment: Just love the two answers: one says top first, the other says bottom first...

Comment: @SolarMike  We were explaining different modes of operation. :-)

Comment: Update for anyone curious about the resolution. Got a better multimeter, and it was only the bottom that was blown. Replaced it and it heated back up.

Comment: @SolarMike JACK and I sorted it out! :)  We were both right! A water heater filled with cold water will certainly turn on the top element first, but once it reaches setpoint, will turn on the bottom element first when some hot water is used.  If a lot is used and the upper part of the WH drops below setpoint, it will turn off the lower element and turn on the upper one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom element always turns on first. Cold water enters the water heater at the bottom via a "dip tube" from the top that directs the cold water to the bottom.   The thermostats that control the elements are staggered. As the WH cooled, the lower element would have kicked in first, probably frying it.  A lot depends upon how long it was empty. Fortunately elements aren't very expensive, you may have to replace both.

Comment: Thanks, George!

From the readings I reported there, can you tell which (or both) appear to be broken? Happy to replace both, but am not completely confident in my interpretation of the resistance readings (worried I am interpreting them backwards).

Answer (score 6):

You should be looking at around 13 ohms for a standard 4500 watt heating element. If an element is burned up, your meter would have 0 deflection.

Our water heaters here in Florida always have the top element going on first because that's the first water leaving the tank and getting into your shower. Once the top thermostat reaches its setting it turns off and turns on the lower element. which stays on until it gets up to its setting. The bottom element will cycle on and off during normal hot water usage but when a lot of water is being used, the top one will start to operate to keep hot water leaving the tank. I have LEDs  hooked up to each element so I'm sure how they work.

My guess  is that you blew the top element because it would go on first but any combination could occur depending on which one was on at the time the draining took place.

Comment: Thanks, Jack!

Given the readings I reported above (multimeter set to 2kΩ, reporting 0.01 on the top and 1.5 on the bottom) does that sound like I blew the top one?

I am a bit confused, because I just opened up a brand new element and tested it, and it shows up as 0.01.

Comment: @evt  Check your ohm scale and  your scale multipliers. Hopefully, you have an analog meter...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a digital meter. The only resistance setting I can choose is "2kΩ". Will that not let me figure this out?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Any meter should get into megaohms.

Comment: Here is the meter. The only resistance setting I see is "2kΩ". https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/a19c1567-3975-4719-bc05-ce24582ba367/svn/commercial-electric-multimeters-bmm-8132r-64_1000.jpg

Comment: You might have to leave the meter hooked up to the element for 30 seconds to resister a correct reading..  I've never liked digital meters for ohms/cap.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but on the 2K ohm scale, .01 would be close to 12.8 ohms which is what you'd expect from a 4,500 watt element.   Here's the math:  4,500/240 = 18.75 amps. Next, I=E/R. Converting that simple equation  to solve for R (ohms) yields 240/18.75 with the end result being 12.8 ohms. So your meter set to the 2K range with a reading of .01 sounds close.  With a reading of 1.5K ohms on the bottom element, it's most likely burned thru.  The biggest problem is when they've blow out like that, they can be hard to remove.

Comment: @JACK  Interesting answer. Here, the bottom element kicks on first, and if the water at the top of the WH gets too cool, it cuts off the bottom element and turns on the top one. 

Also, (and this is a nit pick), on your first sentence, you said if the element had burned out, the reading would be zero.  If an ohm meter, that would be a full blown short, I'm sure that's not what you meant, you probably meant the reading would be infinite resistance.   In reality, because the element, even is burned out, would still register some resistance, which I believe the OP stated at 1.5 on the 2K scale

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Meant 0 deflection.  Are you sure about the elements? You're right about water entering from the bottom of the tank through the dip tube. When the tank is fill, which is when you'd turn on the breaker,  the top element  would come on first to heat up the water so you'd have some hot water fast because that water would exit first. Once that got up to heat, then the bottom kicks in to finish off the lower, colder water entering the tank.

Comment: @JACK completely agree!  I was referring to more normal operation and moderate hot water usage.   On a newly filled, cold tank, the top element would surely come on first, then when it reached setpoint the bottom element would come on.   In my previous house, after an extended power outage, when power was restored, we didn't get any hot water. Turned out the top element was burned out, for who knows how long?! So the top Tstat wouldn't turn on the bottom element until the top was at set point, which wasn't going to happen with  a burned out element!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Completely agree with your normal operation and moderate usage scenario.

Comment: @JACK  I re-read your original post and missed part of the second paragraph...you said it before me about the sequencing of the WH Tstats, and we agree!  Take care.

Comment: @evt: Tangential suggestion: toss that meter and get a better one. Even for a cheap digital multimeter, yours looks unreasonably limited. You should be able to get one with a much wider selection of measuring modes for about $10 or so.

Comment: Thought I would give you helpful folks an update.

Picked up a better multimeter. It was correct the bottom one was the only one blown. I swapped it and everything came back on fine.

Comment: @evt  Did you take an ohm reading on the new element with the new meter???

Comment: @JACK, yes, the new element read 13 ohms. The old working element (upper) read a little over 12. The dead one read nothing. When I pulled it out, a chunk of the element was completely gone.

Comment: @evt   Good luck with your new meter.  There's no fixing a burnt out element.. lol

Comment: @JACK (I may well be missing a joke, but to confirm I am not...) I swapped the broken element for a new one and powered it back on. By no fixing, you just mean I needed to swap it, right?

Comment: @evt  It was a joke.... you mentioned a chunk of the dead element was completely gone... I'm like.. yeah, no soldering any wires to fix that..  I replaced a burnt element and only the threaded  part was left... the whole rest of it was at the bottom of the tank.